# Check if folder is empty without reference issues

Tags: java, dereference

The code below sorts an array of files that it reads from a directory. The only problem is that if the folder is empty then I get a null pointer exception. I have tried a few different ways of checking first if the folder is empty and then executing the below code, but they all used if statements which took this code out of scope. Is there a way I could check if the directory is empty and if it is skip over this code?

```
//sort array listOfFiles by time (oldest to newest)
    File folder = new File(dbBackupLocation + "/" + dbHost);
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
    Arrays.sort(listOfFiles, new Comparator<File>() {
        @Override
                    public int compare(File f1, File f2) {
            return Long.valueOf(f1.lastModified()).compareTo(f2.lastModified());
        }
    });
```

Edit: NullPointerException on line `Arrays.sort(listOfFiles, new Comparator<File>() {`

I used Elliott Frisch code:

```
File folder = new File(dbBackupLocation + "/" + dbHost);
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
    if (listOfFiles != null && listOfFiles.length > 0) {
        // The array isn't empty.
        Arrays.sort(listOfFiles, new Comparator<File>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(File f1, File f2) {
                return Long.valueOf(f1.lastModified())
                        .compareTo(f2.lastModified());
            }
        });
    }
```

But when I try to use listOfFiles like: `for(File s : listOfFiles) { i++; }` I am apparently dereferencing it?

Comment: What do you mean by "took this code out of scope"? can you give an example of how you were using it with if statements?

Comment: Also, when asking a question about an exception, it's helpful to indicate the line where the exception occurred.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you, you want something like

```
File folder = new File(dbBackupLocation + "/" + dbHost);
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
if (listOfFiles != null && listOfFiles.length > 0) {
  // The array isn't empty.
  Arrays.sort(listOfFiles, new Comparator<File>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(File f1, File f2) {
      return Long.valueOf(f1.lastModified())
          .compareTo(f2.lastModified());
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the folder size via a command:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/bin/bash -c du /path/to/Michaels/folder");
```

The 'du' linux command is used for finding the size of a directory.

Please let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Um. This is probably way overkill. Any reason OP can't check whether `listOfFiles` is null or empty *without* spawning a new process?

Comment: You're right, checking the size of listOfFiles is much better.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the folder exists and if it is in fact a folder. Then check the size of listOfFiles:

```
File folder = new File(dbBackupLocation + "/" + dbHost);
if (folder != null && folder.exists() && folder.isDirectory()) {
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
    if (listOfFiles != null && listOfFiles.length > 0) {
        Arrays.sort(listOfFiles, new Comparator<File>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(File f1, File f2) {
                return Long.valueOf(f1.lastModified()).compareTo(f2.lastModified());
            }
        });
    }

    //display the files
    for (File f : listOfFiles) {
        System.out.println(f);
    }
}
```